# How to set query timeout using string-keyed-jdbc-store cache

Tags: configuration, timeout, prepared-statement, infinispan

I want to set the time-out when a java.sql.Statement or PreparedStatement is used to retrieve a cached object from the datastore.

In the docs I cannot find any technique to add this setting using the [xml](https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/9.4/configdocs/infinispan-cachestore-jdbc-config-9.4.html).

Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Regards,
Jeremy

ISPN: 9.4.15.Final

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not currently possible. I've created https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-12825 and a pull request. It should be available in Infinispan 12.1.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I created a [Byteman](https://byteman.jboss.org/) script. To set a 5 minute time-out.

```
# Rules to set a timeout on a Statement reference

RULE Timeout set during Connection.createStatement 
INTERFACE java.sql.Connection
METHOD createStatement
AT RETURN
IF TRUE
DO System.out.println("BYTEMAN:set 300s timeout during createStatement");$!.setQueryTimeout(300)
ENDRULE

RULE Timeout set during Connection.prepareCall
INTERFACE java.sql.Connection
METHOD prepareCall
AT RETURN
IF TRUE
DO System.out.println("BYTEMAN:set 300s timeout during prepareCall");$!.setQueryTimeout(300)
ENDRULE

RULE Timeout set during Connection.prepareStatement
INTERFACE java.sql.Connection
METHOD prepareStatement
AT RETURN
IF TRUE
DO System.out.println("BYTEMAN:set 300s timeout during prepareStatement");$!.setQueryTimeout(300)
ENDRULE
```